# Finding sibling of found element using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I've got a field with a date in it that's identified by a code that's shown in the div previous to it.

```
<div class="fcode">
    <div class="fcode_n">(123)</div> 
    <div class="fcodeText">Date</div>
</div>
<div class="text">09.01.2020</div>
```

All the class names are generic and appear many times, but I can find the div class containing the code I'm after (123) by using

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'151')]")
```

and can find the parent using

```
parent = element.find_element_by_xpath("..")
```

But I'm not stuck on how to find the date in the next element (which is what I'm after). The next element is , I suppose, the following sibling of the parent. There is a 'following_sibling' method like that gets you the sibling of something in your xpath, like this:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'(123)')]/following-sibling::div")
```

but that of course gets me the fcodeText element, not what I'm after - I blv. I need something in the form of

```
parent.find_element_by_xpath("following_sibling")
```

since I'm searching based on an element and not searching the whole document for the sibling following a given bit of text.  I don't seem to find any docs on the use of ".." for finding a parent, but if I could it might have info on an analogous method for sibling instead of parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `parent`:

```
//div[contains(text(),'(123)')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div
```

Answer (score -2):

In any automation project, correct selection of locators makes your automation framework more efficient. Xpath is one of the techniques commonly used in Selenium which enables easy, efficient and reliable automation. It allows tester to navigate through XML structure of any document. We can create xpaths specific to requirement which is a good practice followed often by most of the professional software testing services companies.

As mentioned in your case, where we need to find the date value using **following-sibling parent** relationship, below mentioned pattern will provide you required results -
`//div[text()='(123)']/../following-sibling::div/div`

In generic, following-sibling can be written as -
`//tagname[@attribute='value']//following-sibling::tagname`

This will select all nodes that have same parent as current node and also appears after it.

Comment: I can see the same company linked in almost every answer you posted. How is this relevant to this and other answers?